# can't connect to mysql docker when mount a directory

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerhub

I use official mysql 5.5 docker as database container.
first pull container:

```
docker pull mysql:5.5
```

then I run:

```
docker run --name mysqldb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=testword mysql:5.5
```

it run successfully, and the container mysqldb with ip is 172.17.0.20.And I  can access this mysqldb by this:

```
mysql -h 172.17.0.20 -u root -p # this command from 172.17.0.23
```

input password, then I get this:

```
mysql>
```

this is a test for official mysql. I can access mysqldb from remote host/container.
Then I want to use host directory(store some databases) so I do this:

```
docker run --name mysqldb_with_data -v /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=testword mysql:5.5
```

it run successfully. But when I want to access this mysqldb_with_data container with ip 172.17.0.21, I meet a error:

```
 mysql -h 172.17.0.251 -u root -p # this command from 172.17.0.23
 Enter password: 
 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.23' (using password: YES)
```

I just use host data to replace the data of mysql container, but I can't access mysqldb from remote host/container.I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It works for me. Try your command without any space between `-u` and `root` and between `-p` and `testword`.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue. It was because I have copied `/var/lib/mysql` from **container** to `/var/lib/mysql` on **host** OS by:

`docker cp <container name>:/var/lib/mysql/ /var/lib/`

To copy the /var/lib/mysql in correct way you need to do the following:

1. Get the source of original mount

`docker inspect <container name> | grep -A7 Mounts | grep Source
"Source":"/var/lib/docker/volumes/5a5fcb8c277c6a28f6eea2d156b5703cfc9feb86786ecf61caab95d803773647/_data",`

2. Stop the container

`docker stop <container name>`

3. Copy the data from "Source" to `/var/lib/mysql/`

`mkdir /var/lib/mysql/`

`cp -a /var/lib/docker/volumes/5a5fcb8c277c6a28f6eea2d156b5703cfc9feb86786ecf61caab95d803773647/_data/* /var/lib/mysql/`

After doing this, you'll be able to work with dockerized mysql as expected.

So, basically the problem was with mysql data files, not with dockerezation. To get them in consistent state they should be copied while DB is stopped.